# How to get targeted ads with RevenueHits on a site without text?

Tags: advertising

I've made a kanji learning/testing tool site so there is almost no textual content on the site to target the ads (which are contextual). The result is that I get awful generic ads. How do you push the system to produce better ads without adding context? Hidden text in the site itself gets punished as SEO manipulation, so I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Example ad:
[image: crappy ad sample]

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters SE.  Unfortunately your question, as asked  was off-topic as it called for opinion and product recommendations. . I've deleted your second paragraph to try bring it more in lines with our guidelines.

Comment: Can you add text that isn't hidden?    At the very least you could add some boilerplate to the bottom of every page that might help with ad targeting.  You say "without adding content," but that is exactly what I would try first.